# How to avoid "random" in this jquery function?

Tags: jquery, random

How I can avoid background to change randomly? I would like them to change always in order: green, yellow, grey and after that again green, yellow grey...

http://test.fusionidea.com/proba/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["green", "yellow", "grey"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $('.change').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

Comment: this is changing your color only once, so it won't ever change it from green, to yellow, to gray. are you trying to do that on interval?

Comment: if you want to add this feature so that each time you reload the page you get one different color you have to save the previous color in a persistent way so that you know what is next on reload. This is the reason why the author of this code used rand on the array: to avoid saving in cookie, backend or similar the last color

Comment: I added an answer using SetInterval which I assumed was what you wanted. If it's on refresh you will need to keep the last color stored in LocalStorage or in a Cookie and using that info deciding which color comes next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lelio and Carlos suggested, You should keep a position variable in the local storage to keep track of color changes.
So the code should be something like this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let pos = 0
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('pos') == null){
            window.localStorage.setItem('pos', pos);
```

> If the position hasn't been set, you set the position in Local Storage.

```
        }else{
          pos = window.localStorage.getItem('pos')
          console.log(pos)
        }
        const colors = ["green", "yellow", "grey"];
        $('.change').css("background-color", colors[pos % 3]);
        pos++
        window.localStorage.setItem('pos', pos)
```

> You increment the position.

```
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing your color once... you need to use setInterval to change them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
vat t = 0;
var colors = ["green", "yellow", "grey"];
   setInterval(
         function(){ 
            $('.change').css("background-color", colors[t++]);
            if (t==colors.length) t=0;
         }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: OP wants to do it on page reload and not on a timely base